# Unity Oculus Rift Integration 1.42 disabling distance grabber physics between grabbed object and Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, integration, physics, oculus

Currently I have implemented distance grabber in Unity. My problem is that I would like to disable physics between player and object for countering a wide range of bugs.

I would like to know what would be the correct way to disable the collisions between objects in VR setting.

My current code; does not work in implementation, and is used as extensive module for distance grabbable object. I don't care about the optimality of the code during run-time at the moment, as first step is to actually get the thing to do the bidding.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //this.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
        //this.gameObject.transform.parent = collision.gameObject.transform;
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(this.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(), collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
    }
}
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(this.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(), collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
    }
}
private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{

    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //this.gameObject.transform.parent = null;
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(this.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(), collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
    }
}
```

The commented part I tried testing on, but the OVR distance grabber is designed so that it breaks if I change the parent of object during runtime.

I have checked that most of these problems are not relevant in older versions of Oculus Integration, especially before 1.39.

Answer (score 1):

Use the layer based collision detection feature.  Make one group for the player, one group for the grabbed object, and one for everything else.   When you grab something, move it to the grabbed object layer, and when you let it go, put it back in the everything layer.

Check the checkboxes in edit->project settings->physics so that the player layer and the grabbed object layer don't collide.

Comment: I tested this, actually this method is logically the same as the code above, what I did wrong was that I enabled the collision again in OnCollisionExit(), and that started loop between these 2 states/layers, as the collision is not detected on second layer, as there is no collision possible. I will update my comment soon, today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem is not unambigious.

We can implement a system, which considers deltatime, but the real problem is with the Oculus Rift grabbing system.

I asked around and found out the easiest way to deal with this problem is to discard the Avatar prefab and directly add the CharacterController to the CameraRig gameObject. This way we don't need to deal with the libraries included within Oculus Rift integration package.